# Mail not receiving but sent succesfully using SMTP protocol

Tags: php, codeigniter, protocols, send

I am trying to send email notification for projects. I don't get any error. I got a message like 'email sent successfully'. But not receiving in my email.

Please help me to sort out. I am keeping these bugs nearly two days

The following code I have used

Controller code :

```
$config = array(
    'protocol' => 'sendmail', // 'mail', 'sendmail', or 'smtp'
    'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com', 
    'smtp_port' => 465,
    'smtp_user' => 'info@yosnalab.com',
    'smtp_pass' => 'XXXXXXX',
    'smtp_crypto' => 'ssl', //can be 'ssl' or 'tls' for example
    'mailtype' => 'html', //plaintext 'text' mails or 'html'
    'smtp_timeout' => '10', //in seconds
    'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
    'isSMTP' => TRUE
    );
     $this->email->initialize($config);


 $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
      $this->email->from('info@yosnalab.com','Yosnalab'); // change it to yours
      $this->email->to($friend_mail);// change it to yours
      $this->email->subject('Project notification');
      $this->email->message($message);

 if($this->email->send())
      {
         echo trim('message sent succesfully');
      }
      else
     {
         show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
     }
```

Comment: Did you check your spam box? Sometimes it takes time to receive an email. If you are getting **message sent successfully**, it means it is working.  Now depending upon the server and receiver mail server email will reach.

Comment: No, I didn't receive it in the spam folder too. I checked so many times.

Comment: This may not be a bug. There's a lot of stuff that can go wrong with emails after succesfully sending that will prevent them to be received and even prevent them from being moved to your spam box. Sometimes the receiving server may reject the email (your code will not be aware of this as you can only "see" that your SMTP server accepted it) and not even attempt to deliver it to the destination inbox.

Comment: To better illustrate my point, I sometimes get this kinds of responses from the destination server: `5.7.1 Unfortunately, messages from [X.X.X.X] weren't sent. Please contact your Internet service provider since part of their network is on our block list (S3140) (...)`. I use an email delivery service so I get some more "after-the-fact" visibility, but as long as my code is concerned, my email was accepted by the email delivery service only to get rejected downstream, sometimes long after my code finished running. This may be the case with your email

Comment: Your **PHP** code does not have any problem, in fact, it is sending the email but the ``receiving server`` or the server on which you are ``hosting your service`` me be the real **culprit**.    Read these links https://serversmtp.com/smtp-error/ and      
    https://sendgrid.com/blog/web-api-or-smtp-relay-how-should-you-send-your-mail/ 
    hope it helps you a little.

Comment: I have used Sendmail protocol instead of the SMTP protocol. It is working for the First few email notification but the problem I faced now is the first two mail it's sending after the same error occurs like mail successfully sent but not receiving in the mail. If the problem is the service provider how the first email notification is sending. ??? Could you plz explain me??? @Javier Larroulet

Comment: I have used Sendmail protocol instead of the SMTP protocol. It is working for the First few email notification but the problem I faced now is the first two mail it's sending after the same error occurs like mail successfully sent but not receiving in the mail. If the problem is the service provider how the first email notification is sending. ??? Could you plz explain to me??? @Not A Bot

Comment: @sindhumohan Sendmail is not a protocol. Sendmail is software that uses the SMTP protocol to deliver emails. Email is an intricate machinery. You may successfully pass an email to your outgoing (SMTP) server and that server may accept it (at this point you loose visibility and control about the process), and it may be rejected by the destination server without you ever knowing. This is different from an email being accepted by the destination server and rejected by the recipient's account and sent to spam. Just use sendgrid or mailgun and most of this will go away

Comment: ok. thank you so much. But now it is working fine with even sendmail also. I hope its a server problem. @Javier Larroulet

Comment: If deliverability is a concern, I'd suggest you use an email delivery service (such as Mailgun, Sendgrid, etc). There are either free or cheap alternatives and you'll get a better rate of delivered emails (plus, some tracking you can use to know which emails are actually going through). Thanks to spammers, email delivery "on your own" is pretty much a lottery. It may work some day, it'll definitely not work other days. Hard to predict and hard to control when most of the delivery process is outside your control